# How to add a field to admin without using inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

Based on `django-photologue` I want to let users have their own gallery and want to dispay gallery's owner in admin.

`Inlines` provide additional block of fields at the bottom of admin page. I need just one field `user` that I want to be displayed in the main block of admin page, i.e. among other fields of `Gallery` model).

```
# models
from photologue.models import Gallery
from profiles.models import UserProfile

class GalleryExtended(models.Model):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gallery.title

# admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from photologue.admin import GalleryAdmin as GalleryAdminDefault
from photologue.models import Gallery
from .models import GalleryExtended

class InlineGalleryExtendedAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GalleryExtended

class GalleryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        exclude = ('description', )

class GalleryAdmin(GalleryAdminDefault):
    form = GalleryAdminForm
    save_on_top = True
    inlines = [InlineGalleryExtendedAdmin] # Do not want to use inlines
```

I tried to add to `class GalleryAdmin`:

```
fields = ('user',)  # also tried to add to fieldsets
def user(self, instance):
    return instance.galleryextended.user
```

but it does not work. It works just for `list_display`, i.e.:

```
list_display = ('user',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneToOneField is almost the same as direct inheritance of the needed model, so if make like this:

```
# models.py
from photologue.models import Gallery
from profiles.models import UserProfile

# - class GalleryExtended(models.Model):
class GalleryExtended(Galley):
# -    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

from photologue.admin import GalleryAdmin as GalleryAdminDefault
from photologue.models import Gallery

from .models import GalleryExtended

class GalleryAdmin(GalleryAdminDefault):
    save_on_top = True

admin.site.unregister(Gallery)
admin.site.register(GalleryExtended, GalleryAdmin)
```

`user` field will be inside of the main block. As a downside - at the `site.com/admin` App's subcategory link moves to its own App Category

Answer (score 0):

Add `'user'` to `readonly_fields` and then you can add `'user'` to `fileds`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: then add field `user` and change `save()` in form. And `def user(self, instance):` you can remove, cause return `modelfield` not `formfield`